# Does the GUID passed from a vb.net application be unique in a SQL Server database table?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I want to create a `GUID` in my VB.Net application and save it in the `SQL Server` database table where the column is defined as `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` type. The code is as below:

```
 Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Using trans As SqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
            cmd.Transaction = trans
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [MYTABLE] ([GuidValue]) VALUE @guidValue;"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guidValue", Guid.NewGuid())
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            trans.Commit()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Would the `GUID` be unique in the database table since I am passing it from the VB.Net application instead of generating it in the SQL server itself (using `NEWID()` or `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` functions)?

I would prefer to generate the GUID in my VB.net application if it is going to be unique in the database. Otherwise I would generate it in SQL server and read it back to the application.

Any advise would be much appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.100).aspx), a GUID has a "very low probability of being duplicated"

But there are pros and cons you should look at [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/)